# Gather data in r with multiple columns

Tags: r

I have some data which I am trying to use tidy R and pivot longer function in R to get the out put as mentioned below. But I am not able to do it, I am getting Data

I have data in this format. ( with many other column names )

```
Country State   Year 1  Population 1    Year 2  Population2
U.S.A   IL  2009    20000   2010    30000
U.S.A   VA  2009    30000   2010    40000
```

I want to get data in this format.

```
Country State   Year    Population
U.S.A   IL  2009    20000
U.S.A   IL  2010    30000
U.S.A   VA  2009    30000
U.S.A   VA  2010    40000
```

I am able to do it only for on column, but not able to pass other column likes like population

My code is below.

```
file1<-file %>%
 pivot_longer(
   cols = contains("Year"),
   names_sep = "_",
  names_to = c(".value", "repeat"),

 )
```

I was able to make it work on Tidyverse.

```
library(tidyverse)
file<-read_excel("peps300.xlsx")

names(file)<-str_replace_all(names(file), c("Year " = "Year_" , "Num " = "Num_", "DRate " = "DRate_" , "PRate " = "PRate_",  "Denom " = "Denom_"))

file<-file %>%
 pivot_longer(
   cols = c(contains("Year"),contains("Num"),contains("DRate"),contains("PRate"),contains("Denom")),
   names_sep = "_",
  names_to = c(".value", "repeat")
 )
```

Comment: The column names in your data, doesn't show `_`, but have space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to specify the `cols` that `starts_with` "Population" or "Year"

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = c(starts_with("Population"), starts_with("Year")), 
    names_to = c(".value", "group"), names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)")
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  Country State group Population  Year
#  <chr>   <chr> <chr>      <int> <int>
#1 U.S.A   IL    1          20000  2009
#2 U.S.A   IL    2          30000  2010
#3 U.S.A   VA    1          30000  2009
#4 U.S.A   VA    2          40000  2010
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Country = c("U.S.A", "U.S.A"), State = c("IL", 
"VA"), Year_1 = c(2009L, 2009L), Population_1 = c(20000L, 30000L
), Year_2 = c(2010L, 2010L), Population_2 = c(30000L, 40000L)), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: I tried this, but it gives double pivot, first by Population, and then by year. so I get double the rows.

Comment: Please check your dataset. I showed with a data reproducible

Comment: I am new in R, but somehow I am getting error on dplyr, but I am able to use tidyverse. Pleas see my code above( included in question, at the bottom). It works like a charm now.

Comment: @newubuntugeek  What is the error you are getting?  At the end you said it works.  So, it must be a version issue which got solved when you added the `tidyverse` (which also loads dplyr)?

Answer (score 1):

```r
df %>%
    pivot_longer(
        -c(Country,State),
        names_to = c(".value","group"),
        names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+)"
    )
```

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Country State group Year  Population
  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     
1 U.S.A   IL    1     2009  20000     
2 U.S.A   IL    2     2010  30000     
3 U.S.A   VA    1     2009  30000     
4 U.S.A   VA    2     2010  40000
```

You can then drop the `group` if you don't need it.

And, to do this, you will need to clean your column names first. Make sure they all follow the same pattern and words are connected with a single space or a single underscore.

```r
df <- structure(list(Country = c("U.S.A", "U.S.A"), State = c("IL", 
"VA"), Year_1 = c("2009", "2009"), Population_1 = c("20000", 
"30000"), Year_2 = c("2010", "2010"), Population_2 = c("30000", 
"40000")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: I have many other variables, so can you please help me on a method in which I don't have to use -c(Country,State), instead I can specify the columns to put pivot on, like population and  year.